# Has Hyperledger Fabric improved performance since V1.1

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

There is a [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1801.10228) published by IBM about the performance benchmark of Hyperledger Fabric V1.1. I am wondering since now Hyperledger Fabric is at V1.4, has the performance improved? Where can I find the benchmark for v1.2,v1.3 and v1.4? Thank you in advance